# Livewire magic actions not working Uncaught ReferenceError: $event is not defined

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="mb-5">
                                <label class="form-label">Order: </label>
                                <select wire:change="selectOrder($event.target.value)">
                                    @foreach($orders as $option)
                                        <option value="{{$option['id']}}">{{$option['id']}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```php
public function selectOrder($order)
{
    $this->order = $order;
    $this->products = $this->order->products;
}
```

[image]

here is a live wire component that has a select input I need when changing the select the function `selectOrder` is executed with the selected value, i use `$event` magic action but i got the following error.

Comment: Did you published the assets? And included livewire styles and scripts tags?

Comment: yes, i made sure of this, @KaleemShoukat

Comment: Wrap your component in div and try again

Comment: @KaleemShoukat I edited the question with a full code

Comment: which browser you are using? This might be issue of browser but I'm not sure. Please try using another browser.

Comment: Replace parent div of select like this <div x-data> and try again.

Comment: i'm using chrome, i tries all other browsers but same issue, edage, fireofox,

Comment: i edited the code to look like this but same issue   `<div class="mb-5" x-data>
                                <label class="form-label">Order: </label>
                                <select wire:change="selectOrder($event.target.value)">
                                    @foreach($orders as $option)
                                        <option value="{{$option['id']}}">{{$option['id']}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>`

Comment: Are you using Alpine JS also? If yes then you should use <div class="mb-5" x-data>  this.

Comment: yes i'm using alpine here is my main app .js 
`require('./bootstrap');

require('alpinejs');
`

Comment: Then visit this link and check the related syntax https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-and-alpine-js-wire-is-not-defined

Comment: can you see the loaded assets in html inspector?

Comment: I'm sure your syntax is not correct. Search for it.

Comment: i'm tryingto upload image here but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$event` is the Alpine.js magic property.
So one way to solve it is to have use an Alpine.js event listener, that calls the Livewire method.

```
<select x-on:change="$wire.selectOrder($event.target.value)">
```

That said, you could use a property in the Livewire class, and bind the select to a model,

```
<select wire:model="orderValue">
```

And then in the component listen for that change.

```php
public $orderValue;

// ...

public function updated($field, $value)
{
    if ($field === 'orderValue') {
        $this->selectOrder($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: this works just fine but what is wrong with my code i just can't figure it out
@Qirel

Comment: Like I said, the `$event` is not a Livewire, but an Alpine.js magic property. It can only be used within Alpine.js listeners.